# findViewById return null only for one element

Tags: java, android

I have been reading several posts about it but the common solutions did not work in my case (or maybe I didn't understand how to implement them because I am learning)...

The problem is that only two of the three values that I enter arrive correctly, the "email" always comes out null (I can see it when debugging) and I really don't understand why only that flaw.

This is the **activity_sign_in.xml**:

```
...
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SignName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Nombre"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SignEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Correo"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SignPass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Contraseña"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
...
```

And this is de **SignIn.java**

```
...
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText name, email, pass;
    Button saveButton;
    String username, mail, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SignName);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SignEmail); //This one always comes null
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SignPass);
        saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    username = name.getText().toString(); //It's Ok
    mail = email.getText().toString(); //It's null
    password = pass.getText().toString(); //It's Ok
}
```

Comment: where you use email?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you provided here. By saying it comes as null, Do you mean the `View` is null or you get a null value out of the input?

Comment: @JohnJoe, In public void onClick(View v), as a variable "String mail = email.getText().toString();"

Comment: @ZankrutParmar I enter the values to the input (and I can see the values), but at the code level it is null, it is not a visual problem (if that's what you're trying to say)

Comment: @ÇhristoferParra No I understood your problem. Adding the code of `onClick` method and where you get the `null` value in the question will be helpful in your case then.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar, yes, I already updated it

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code. Post your logcat where you get the null value. Your code has no problem in it.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar after some debugging time it worked magically ... I had already done a rebuild of the project but it hasn't worked, now i was just testing and it was fixed, lol, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem in the `String maill = email.getText().toString()` code. Though I want to point out that if you are declaring the `String maill` inside `onClick` method and calling it from some other method to print log, you might get a `null` value. I suggest declaring the String as global variable for your activity and try again.

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText name, email, pass;
Button saveButton;
String maill,pwd;//Declare your strings here.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){......}
```

Comment: I did what you mention but when trying to print the variable I got a NullPointerException ... I tried the same but with the others fields (name and password) and it prints them without problems, it is just the email

Comment: Okay, Can you add the code of your `OnClick` method and the code where you print the variable. Edit that in the question.

Comment: it finally corrected itself, but thanks for the annotation

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be due to two possible errors.

Error 1: You might get a null value for an object of an edit text if you refer to an ID of a different view/viewgroup from a different layout. Just make sure that "SignEmail" is referred to from the "activity_sign_in" layout.

Error 2: This might be due to android studio sometimes. Try rebuilding the project and run the code again.

Comment: Hi, I only have that layout (it was the first thing I checked anyway) and I already rebuild the project :(